# mysql query to compare 2 types of dates when actual date unknown

Tags: mysql, updates

Is it posaible to write a query when you don't know any acutal dates? I need to compare transaction dates with funds available dates & update the funds available date by adding a day to the date.

Answer (score -1):

I know MS SQL better than MySQL, but you still should be able to compare them using greater than and less than.  If you want to modify the value, you'll want to use the DATE_ADD function ([Date and Time functions reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)).  Comparing transaction date to the funds available date would involve something like `WHERE TransTable.TransDate >= CustTable.FundsAvailDate`, and then adding one day to the funds available date would be something like `SET FundsAvailDate = DATE_ADD(FundsAvailDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

Comment: I got an error message when I did the SET command: Error Code: 1193
Unknown system variable 'funds_avail_date'

Comment: Obviously you would have to adapt this example to suit your schema.

Comment: Please **do not** reference w3schools in answers. The information there is woefully out of date and usually contains severe security vulnerabilities do to atrociously bad coding standards used in the examples. The [Official MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) should suffice.

Comment: @tadman good point, I've updated the answer to use your link.